# Filter in custom Django tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tagging

I created a custom tag, that accepts a parameter:

```
{% panel "most" %}
```

I would use the `add` to the parameter:

```
{% panel "most"|add:"_people" %}
```

I expect the parameter will be "most_people", but instead it is "most"|add:"_people". It seems that filters are not invoked inside custom tags. How to make them work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `simple_tag` decorator to write your custom tag, you should be able to use a filters on the arguments.

However, if you have written an [advanced template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#with), then you will need to do extra work to make `"most"|add:"_people"` use the filter as you want.

One work around, is to use the [`{% with %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#advanced-custom-template-tags) tag to assign the result of the filter to a variable.

```
{% with panel_name="most"|add:"_people" %}
{% panel panel_name %}
{% endwith %}
```